# Show that the semisimple and nilpotent parts of $x \in L$ are the sums of the semisimple and nilpotent parts

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $L = L_1 \oplus···\oplus L_t$ be the decomposition of a semisimple Lie algebra $L$ into its simple ideals. Show that the semisimple and nilpotent parts of $x \in L$ are the sums of the semisimple and nilpotent parts in the various $L_i$ of the components of $x$.

**Comments:** Let $x \in L$, $x=x_1+···+x_t$ with $x_i \in L_i$, and $x_i=u_i+v_i$ is the Jordan decomposition of $x_i \in L_i$, $u_i$ is
semisimple and $v_i$ is nilpotent. Define $u=u_1+···+u_t$ and $v=v_1+···+v_t$.

I'm thinking of showing that $u$ is semisimples in $L$ and $v$ is nilpotent in $L$ and for this to use abstract Jordan decomposition, that is, show that, $ad_L(x)=ad_L(u)+ad_L(v)$. My idea is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a homework question for Humphrey's book on Lie algebras. It has solutions online [here](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~zhchang/Research/Notes_01_STLA.pdf), on page $20$. There is a typo in the solution, it should be $[u_i,u_j]=0$ for all $i\neq j$.

Comment: why i need $[u,v]=0$?

Comment: Because of the definition of the Jordan decomposition: $x=u+v$ with $[u,v]=0$. We can easily have examples with $x=u+v$ with $[u,v]\neq 0$, but these no Jordan decompositions.

Comment: I do not need to show that $[ad(u),ad(v)]=0$? Or this is an consequence of $[u,v] = 0$?

Comment: Yes, $[ad(u),ad(v)]=ad([u,v])$ because $ad$ is a representation.

Comment: The link is not valid anymore I think. Can you please explain shortly how to finish the proof? (How to conclude that $[u_i,u_j]=$ (and same for $v_i$, and why $u,v$ commute?). @Dietrich Burde

Comment: @user726608 There are several other links now for the solutions, e.g., [this one](https://www.coursehero.com/file/17364486/Notes-01-STLA/). Just google "Humphreys Lie algebras solutions".